# Flutter - I want to know how to store first click datetime to set condition

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to set condition that in one hour after clicking first time, butI don't know how to store first-click datetime. I know that DateTime.now keep changing after clicking, so it would not stop after 5 times.

```
int count = 0;
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
Duration difference = DateTime.now().difference(now);
          if(difference.inMinutes < 60){
                        count++;
                        if(count <= 5){
                          isRewardedVideoAvailable =
                          await FlutterApplovinMax.isLoaded(listener);
                          if (isRewardedVideoAvailable) {
                            FlutterApplovinMax.showRewardVideo(
                                    (AppLovinAdListener event) => listener(event));

                          }
                          print("points" + points.toString());
                          print("idok$count");
                        }
                        else{

                        }
```

Comment: Store how? Permanently? Just during the session? You should be more specific.

Comment: Sorry, it should be like when I click, in one hour after first click I can click only 5 times. Next hour, I can click more 5 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a small application to simulate what you want to do (with comments added as explanation). I've replaced one hour to five seconds so you can reproduce it like a champ!

```dart
class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  DateTime _firstClickTime;
  int _clickCount = 0;
  int _remainingSeconds;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        // Displays how many clicks were done in the last time window
        Text("Click count: $_clickCount"),

        // Displays how many seconds to the next time window
        Text(_remainingSeconds == null 
             ? "Ok"
             : "Hey, wait $_remainingSeconds seconds before clicking!"),

        // The button the user should click
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
            
            // If the first click is not defined, define it right now!
            if (_firstClickTime == null) {
              _firstClickTime = now;
            } 
            
            // Calculate the time difference between now and the
            // first time the button was clicked
            final Duration diff = now.difference(_firstClickTime);
            
            // If this difference is less than five seconds
            if (diff.inSeconds < 5) {
              // If the click count has reach its maximum (5 clicks)
              if (_clickCount == 5) {
                // Don't increase the click count, display to the
                // user how many seconds he has left to click again
                setState(() => _remainingSeconds = 5 - diff.inSeconds);

              } else {
                setState(() {
                  // Remove the remaining seconds message
                  _remainingSeconds = null;
                  
                  // Increment the click count since it's within
                  // the allowed time difference 
                  _clickCount++;
                });
              }

            // If it's greater than five seconds
            } else {
              // Reset the first time the button was clicked and
              // the click count, so the user can click it again
              _firstClickTime = null;
              _clickCount = 0;
            }
          },
          child: Text("Click me!"),
        )
      ]
    );
  }
}
```